# Where to get 3D files for LEGO bricks?

Tags: 3d-printing

I am constantly in search for a particular rare brick from the 1990's which is ridiculously expensive on BrickLink and also hard to get. So I am thinking about printing it on a 3D printer to be able to finish projects. I understand, a blasphemous behaviour. Please let me know where to get the needed 3D file.

Comment: LEGO doesn't (3D) print their bricks, especially not in the 90ies where 3D-printing (almost) wasn't invented yet. So you're looking for a file some random person has made for his/her own use. I've never seen a repository of such files.

Comment: well, i thought there are 3D programms that one can use for designing models and there is a library for the bricks. i would like to extract the one brick as a file. btw, the brick is in use also today but not in the color that i am looking for

Comment: What part are you looking for?

Comment: hi chicks, I am looking for "6192 - Brick, Modified 2 x 4 No Studs, Curved Top". It is a common piece but not in white. It was only used in 1995 in 3 sets. It would be great to have a STL so I can print it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canonical location for 3D models of LEGO bricks would be [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org), with its huge catalogue of [official parts](http://www.ldraw.org/library/updates/complete.zip).

Another resource specifically catered to the 3D printing community is [PrintABrick](https://printabrick.org/bricks/). Their library is not as big as LDraw's, but they offer ready-to-print STL files.

Comment: LDraw files are suitable for digital modeling, but not for 3D printing.

Comment: @Alex Good to know! What _renders_ them unsuitable for 3D printing?

Comment: LDraw parts have just geometry. You still need to tweak dimensions, tolerances and directions after conversion. So they are not ready to be used directly for 3D printing.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer Alex. My friend with the 3d printer says that he needs STL files. Would I be able to produce those with LDraw?

Comment: There is a perl script/library ldraw2stl https://github.com/kristov/ldraw2stl to convert LDraw data files to stl format that can be printed just fine.